# What is the difference between xarray.open_mfdataset(parallel=True) and xarray.concat when using dask arrays?

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray

I'm working with a classic data processing workflow using python, i.e. loading a large number of files, pre-processing them, concatenating them and applying a few reductions.

At the moment, I'm using a two-stage workflow with dask:

1. I create a dask `Bag` to load and preprocess all the input files and export the resulting xarray `DataSet` with dimensions `(time, lat, lon, fileidx)` as a zarr file to disk.
2. I open all the previous zarr files with `xarray.open_mfdataset` to concatenate them along the `fileidx` dimension and apply the final reduction.

Everything works fine this way and the parallelization applies well to both steps.

I naively tried to simplify this two-step workflow into a single step by using the `xarray.concat` function directly on the output `DataSet` of the first step instead of the zarr write/read step, but in all my attempts `xarray.concat` merged everything using a single worker and thus crashed my calculation due to a memory problem.

So do you know the difference between `xarray.concat` and `xarray.open_mfdataset` concatenation? Or maybe how to manage to do it if it is possible? With small data, the result is (it seems at least) the same.

This is how I write and read zarr files currently:

```py
# Write
import dask.bag as db

my_data = db.from_sequence(input_files)
            .map(preprocessing)
            .map(to_dataset)
            .map(lambda x: x.chunk(None))
my_data.map(lambda x: x.to_zarr(f"{ZARR_STORE_PATH}/part_{x.fileidx.data.item():02}.zarr")).compute()

# Read
xr.open_mfdataset(
    Path(ZARR_STORE_PATH).glob("part_*.zarr"),
    engine="zarr",
    combine="nested",
    concat_dim="fileidx",
    parallel=True,
)
```

And some code I tried:

```py
xr.concat(my_data, dim="fileidx")
xr.concat(my_data.to_delayed(), dim="fileidx")
dask.delayed(lambda x: xr.concat(x, dim="fileidx"))(my_data)
```

There is also a discussion here: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/4628

Answer (score 0):

The following two options are independent

- open_mfdataset(parallel=True) opens and reads metadata from all input datasets in parallel
- chunks={} (or similar) produces dask.arrays as the backing object for each read

You probably wanted the second one when creating your overall dataset. Also, although you can create such things within delayed, it is more normal to call these "collection" API functions from the client instead, else things can go wrong.

On `concat`, this will create a lazy massive array of all datasets; so if you operate on it, it will either load the whole thing (without `chunks`) or use dask to work on the whole data chunkwise. Otherwise, `concat` in the client should be very similar to `open_mfdataset`.